# How do you match values in two different columns on two different text file?

Tags: matching

I need to extract the columns "MID" from my data txt file & also "MID" from my BahamaBucks txt file to see if they have matching numbers but I am unsure on how to do that. I am using R

BahamaBucks <- fread("../bahama bucks active MIDs.txt",  header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")

Data <-  fread("../5041 Pull.txt",  header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")

DataOnly <- left_join (BahamaBucks, Data, by = "MID")

all <- left_join(BahamaBucks, Data, by = "MID" )

write.table(all, "../all.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

write.table(DataOnly , "../DataOnly .txt", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)